# Install driver in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration

i have problems connecting to an Oracle Database, i´ve configured the connection but it says:

```
    Error connecting to database [_____] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' could not be found, make sure the 'Oracle' driver (jar file) is installed.
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:472)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
```

I´ve downloaded the driver but i don´t know where to put it. I can´t find any lib-ext folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Put your driver into de data-integration/lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

put this driver in lib folder you can find the path of lib folder as **data-integration/lib**